# An INSERT conditioned on COUNT

Tags: sql, mysql, insert, count, conditional-statements

How can I construct a MySQL INSERT query that *only* executes if the number of rows satisfying some condition already in the table is less than 20, and fails otherwise?

That is, if the table has 18 rows satisfying the condition, then the INSERT should proceed. If the table has 23 rows satisfying the condition, then the INSERT should fail.

For atomicity, I need to express this in a single query, so two requests can not INSERT at the same time, each in the 'belief' that only 19 rows satisfy the condition.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

What about:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable(Column1, Column2, ...)
    SELECT 'Value For Column 1', 'Value For Column 2', ...
      FROM Dual
     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TargetTable WHERE ...Some Condition...) < 20;
```

If the WHERE clause is not satisfied, no row is inserted; if the where clause is satisfied, then one row is inserted.

You can adapt the same mechanism to select from another table (instead of a single row of values from DUAL).

Comment: This is fantastic! Quick question though, is using a subquery in this manner atomic? If many inserts like this are happening at once, is it possible for there to end up being more insertions than should be allowed?

Comment: That's going to depend on the minutiae of how the DBMS manages transactions, etc, and also on isolation levels.  It might also depend on having appropriate enforced keys (primary key, unique constraints) on the table.  In principle, you should not get a problem because if two transactions try to insert the same record, one should succeed and the other should fail.  But you'll need to read the manual rather carefully to be sure that's what actually happens.

Comment: The only constraint I'm concerned about in this example is the count. If the same query is run twice simultaneously with the same count conditions (the values of the insert can be arbitrary, there are no uniqueness constraints), then the whole operation, including the subquery, would need to be atomic. Otherwise, both could return < 20 from the subquery and then both inserts would be made, even if the first resulted in the count incrementing to 20. In this instance, the question is specifically about MySQL; I could dig in the manual, but do you have a quick answer?

Comment: I don't have a quick answer; it is a low enough level of detail that I've not had the opportunity to explore, validate, check or learn what goes on.

Comment: Cool. It's worth looking into more then. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Okay, I dug a little bit more. According to the answer posted here, such a query will be executed atomically if the table's storage engine supports transactions (such as InnoDB, but not MyISAM): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816062/is-mysql-query-containing-sub-query-atomic

Comment: That fits in with what I know of MySQL, but I wasn't prepared to risk misleading you by making the statement without research to back it up, and I didn't really have the time to do that today.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How can this statement be done with the same table? I.e. only insert a new column into the table if there are less than x rows for that particular ID?

Comment: @anna — even now, 6+ years later, I don't often run MySQL.  If the discussion above doesn't help and you can't try it, then maybe you should ask another question on SO, probably cross-referencing this one and explaining the information it is lacking.  (Also note that you insert rows into a table, not just single columns — except in the unusual circumstance that a table only has one column, but even then, you insert a row that happens to have a single column in it).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can get of is just lock the table, count records, perform operations, unlock the table.

```
LOCK TABLES t WRITE;

perform count

decide - to insert or not in your programming language

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Really? I would think that a more clever solution existed. Like:

"SELECT COUNT(...) ...; IF ... THEN INSERT ...;".

I just can't find that right syntax.

Comment: @Anders Feder: you cannot get atomic count + comparison + performing insert, because there is no such in mysql. And what is wrong with LOCK actually? `"SELECT COUNT(...) ...; IF ... THEN INSERT ...;"` how should this behave without any locks?

Comment: I am not well-versed in MySQL, but I had hoped the query could be constructed such that either the IF condition is satisfied or the whole query fails. How would it be done with locks, though? Thanks.

Comment: @Anders Feder: added sketch for the solution that uses programming language + mysql.

Comment: Thanks. My programming language is PHP. What will happen if the request (program execution) is terminated in between acquiring and releasing the lock? Will it be released automatically - do you know?

Comment: @Anders Feder: yes, it will be released automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @varaibleOne int;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
select
@varaibleOne=SUM(case when (condition satisfied) then 1 else 0 end)
from table where (if you have anything)

IF(@varaibleOne<=20)
begin
insert into table ()
end
```

The wait for statement is not sure.. u can google it..

Comment: your solution does not solve his issue, since it is not atomic.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to get a query to actually throw an *error* is by using the [SIGNAL command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) - which is only accessible in MySQL 5.5, inside of stored procedures.

Is it acceptable to create a stored procedure to embody this task?  If so, it is possible to do what you want.

Otherwise, about your only option is to run two queries - one to check the number of rows, and another to insert new rows if there are enough rows to meet your condition.

This could also be done in a stored procedure (or a function), so that you could call it with one query from your code.